# How to use translation in helper functions in Vue3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

In my Vue application, I use translations using vue-i18n (https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/). My main.ts looks like this:

```
// Create vue app
const app = createApp(App)

// Use plugins
app.use(i18n)
....

// Mount vue app
app.mount('#app')
```

Translations are applied in my components - so everything works like a charm.

Now I want to create a helper function that allows me to format durations in human readable form at mutliple places in my app - e.g. "4 minutes, 2 seconds" (in English) and "4 Minuten, 2 Sekunden" (in German).

So I created a helper function in a separate file:

```
export default {
  formatDuration: (value: number) => {
    if (!value){
        return null;
    }
    
    let duration = dayjs.duration(value, "seconds");
    let secondsPart = duration.seconds();
    let minutesPart = duration.minutes();
    return (duration + " " + $t("seconds")); // build error
  }
}
```

the last line has an compilation error, as there's no $t. How can I access the translation system and resolve a string according to the current language, when I'm not in vue component context.

Comment: You need to export createI18n instance from a separate module like i18n.js and import it where needed

Comment: can you guide me a bit?

Comment: `export const i18n = createI18n({...})` in i18n.js.

Comment: That way I create a copy which I need to configure again. But I was able to solve it accessing getCurrentInstance()

Comment: Can you clarify? There should be only 1 i18n instance, and it should be in a separate module, so it could be imported. getCurrentInstance should be used with caution, especially in random places like helpers because an instance can be unavailable

Comment: The docs you are seeing are for Vue 2. There are other docs for Vue 3. You can look at this https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html Convert your helper function to composition API style and use it